# How to Diagnose Random "Error establishing a database connection" with WordPress

Tags: mysql, azure, wordpress

I maintain a Linux VM in Azure which contains one MySQL instance and 8 databases within that instance. Each database is used by a WordPress front end also hosted in Azure App Services.

When using my WordPress sites, I will randomly receive:

`Error establishing a database connection.`

`A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`.

The user/pass for the databases in `wp-config` are correct because it will work and then not work and then work again in the span of 5 minutes.

I'm not even sure where to begin diagnosing this. Can anyone offer some advice on relevant logs to look at?

Comment: What do the MySQL logs say?

Comment: @JayMcTee I've checked the general error log and didn't see anything. And the detailed full log fills up with a ton of queries to the point where it's impossible to decipher anything useful. I'm not even sure the connection is making it to the MySQL process.